# NSPathControl will not display placeholderString when bound to a value

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nspathcontrol

Subject says is all.

I created an NSPathControl with a placeholder message in IB. Ran app, placeholder text appears.

I then bound the value of the control to an NSURL* property of my controller. Now, the placeholder text never appears, even when the property value is nil.

Stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the placeholder in the binding, under the appropriate fields No Selection Placeholder and/or Null Placeholder.

Comment: Thanks! Null Placeholder was the missing piece to the puzzle.